# Why does my legend not match the colour of my bars in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

I converted the bars of my graph from gray with a coloured outline to a solid fill which resulted in half of my error bars not being visible due to being the same colour. I therefore changed the colour of the error bars to black to improve contrast but this has resulted in the items of my legend all being black and I cannot find a way to make the legend match the colour of my bars without making a complete mess of the graph (e.g. bars stacking on top of each other and error bars disappearing).

My data is as follows:

```
emean_Sleep_State <- c('WAKE','SWS','REM','WAKE','SWS','REM','WAKE','SWS','REM')
emean_Treatment <- c('Disturbed','Disturbed','Disturbed','Recovery','Recovery','Recovery','UnDisturbed','UnDisturbed','UnDisturbed')

emean_Means <- c(31.2,48.8,23.2,28.2,50.1,24.1,27.7,49.9,24.2)
emean_SE <- c(2.91,2.80,2.80,2.87,2.74,2.78,2.92,2.81,2.81)

emeanframe <- data.frame(emean_Sleep_State,emean_Treatment,emean_Means,emean_SE)

Estimated_Max_Means_emean <- emeanframe$emean_Means + emeanframe$emean_SE
Estimated_Min_Means_emean <- emeanframe$emean_Means - emeanframe$emean_SE

emeanframe <- data.frame(emean_Sleep_State,emean_Treatment,emean_Means,emean_SE,Estimated_Max_Means_emean,Estimated_Min_Means_emean)

realvalueemean <- apply(emeanframe[,c(3,5,6)],2,FUN=backtransANG)

emeanframe$realmean <- realvalueemean[,1]
emeanframe$realmaxmean <- realvalueemean[,2]
emeanframe$realminmean <- realvalueemean[,3]
```

Similarly, the code I used to create my graphs is:

```
emeanplot <- ggplot(as.data.frame(emeanframe$'emean_Treatment')
                ,aes(x = factor(emeanframe$'emean_Sleep_State'),emeanframe$'realmean'
                     ,color=emeanframe$'emean_Treatment'))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = 'dodge',fill = c('#F8766D','#F8766D','#F8766D','#00BA38','#00BA38','#00BA38','#619CFF','#619CFF','#619CFF')) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c('WAKE','SWS','REM')) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=emeanframe$'realminmean'
                    ,ymax=emeanframe$'realmaxmean')
                ,width=0.2,position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),linewidth=1) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black','black','black'))+
  xlab('Sleep State') + ylab('Proportion of Behaviour') + labs(color = "Type of Night",size=14) + ylim(0,1) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14)) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=14))
```

I'm not sure exactly what I am doing wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried some permutations of scale_color_manual, scale_fill_manual, colour=c('') but not have resulted in a solution. Namely, my legend is still 3 black boxes which do not match my bars which are red, green and blue.

Comment: What ist ```backtransANG```? We don't have that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You could solve this way:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(emeanframe,
       aes(x = emean_Sleep_State,
           y = realmean,
           fill = emean_Treatment)) +
  
  geom_col(position = 'dodge', 
           colour = "black", 
           alpha = 0.5) + # this is what makes the errorbars visible!
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = realminmean,
                    ymax = realmaxmean,
                    colour = emean_Treatment),
                width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                linewidth = 1) + 
  
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c('WAKE','SWS','REM')) + 
  labs(x = 'Sleep State',
       y = 'Proportion of Behaviour',
       fill = "Type of Night",
       color = "Type of Night") +
  # ylim(0, 1) + # commented out because I dont have the backtransANG function that I currently replaced with I()
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y  = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]

I cleaned up a bit your code because you are not supposed to use `$` to call the right columns inside of `aes`.

The important change I made to solve your problem is to add `alpha = 0.5` into `geom_col` (`geom_col` is literally `geom_bar` when `stat = 'identity'`)

What else I changed:

- I removed `fill` in `geom_bar` (now `geom_col`) because it wasn't necessary since I replaced `colour` in the first `aes` with `fill`
- I wrote `colour = "black"` to draw a line around the bars
- I wrote `colour = emean_Treatment` to colour the errorbar like the bars
- `scale_colour_manual` wasn't necessary anymore
- I set all the labels into `labs` (and add `fill`)
- I merged together all the `themes`

### Alternative

Alternatively, if you just want the legend to match the bars and you want the errorbars in black, you can use this code:

```r
ggplot(emeanframe,
       aes(x = emean_Sleep_State,
           y = realmean,
           fill = emean_Treatment)) +
  
  geom_col(position = 'dodge',
           colour = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = realminmean,
                    ymax = realmaxmean),
                colour = "black",
                width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                linewidth = 1) + 
  
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c('WAKE','SWS','REM')) + 
  labs(x = 'Sleep State',
       y = 'Proportion of Behaviour',
       color = "Type of Night") +
  # ylim(0, 1) + # commented out because I dont have the backtransANG function that I currently replaced with I()
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y  = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]

Here:

- I set `colour = "black"` into `geom_errorbar`
- I removed `alpha = 0.5` because it was no longer needed

### How I created you data

I didn't know what `backtransANG` was so I just wrote like this:

```r
realvalueemean <- apply(emeanframe[,c(3,5,6)], 2, FUN = I)
```

In your plot you may want to uncomment `ylim(0,1) +`